# Configuring a self-signed certificate

Tags: asp.net-core-5.0

I am trying to configure a self-signed certificate via appsettings.json file.
I exported my existing IIS certificate to a pfx file.
And then I have this in my appsettings.json:

```html
"Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "Https": {
        "Url": "https://MYDOMAIN:5001",
        "Certificate": {
          "Path": "c:\\1\\IIScert.pfx",
          "Password": "12345"
        }
      }
    }    
  }
```

It completely ignores it and listens on 5000 via http instead.

I then tried to configure it via program.cs file with slightly more luck:

```html
        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                    webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(serverOptions =>
                    {

                        serverOptions.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 5001, listenOptions =>
                        {
                            listenOptions.UseHttps(@"C:\1\IIScert.pfx", "12345");
                        });
                    });

                });
```

It runs on Firefox but returns "ERR_HTTP2_INADEQUATE_TRANSPORT_SECURITY" on Chrome.

Why is it ignoring my appsettings.json, and why doesn't it work on Chrome?
I am able to access my IIS website using this cert on Chrome without issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The appsettings.json settings weren't used because apparently it's needed to load the file also in program.cs and not just startup.cs as I had it

```html
        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {

                    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile($"appsettings.json", optional: true).Build();

                    webBuilder.UseConfiguration(config);

                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();                                        

                });
    }
```

As for setting a certificate via code, it's needed to set.

```html
listenOptions.Protocols = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.HttpProtocols.Http1;
```

This can also be done in appsettings.json

As for why Http2 returns the Chrome error, see this bug report.
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/41175